# How are two seats supposed to fit side by side into a 3 ft 8 in (~1.15 m) wide cabin?

Tags: aircraft-design, cabin-design, seats, cabin

According to [GlobalAir](https://www.globalair.com/aircraft-for-sale/Specifications?specid=157), the Cessna P210N "Pressurized Centurion" has a cabin width of 3 ft 8 in (~1.15 m). However are two seats (plus some space inbetween to be able to get through to the rear seats) supposed to fit into that space ? These seats can't be more than 40 cm wide ! Even I would only just fit on them, and I am not very thick !

Comment: I suspect they simply made an error.  From the picture (and experience of similar Cessnas), I think it's probably closer to 5 ft 8 in, which suggests whoever typed up the web page misread the 5 as a 3.

Comment: @jamesqf I don't think that, because the three-view in the POH of the Cessna P210N suggests a similar cabin width.

Comment: The seat I'm on is 40cm wide and I fit just fine.

Comment: @Programmer: Suggest you take a measuring tape out to your local airport :-)

Comment: You don’t get into the back of Cessna’s by going between the seats. You pull the seat forward as far as it goes and get into the back directly. You do need to go between the seats to get to the third row, but only small people fit there and there’s enough room to squeeze through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some dimensions

[image: Cessna 210 dimensional drawing 1]
([Source](https://www.the-blueprints.com/blueprints/modernplanes/cessna/46858/view/cessna_210_centurion/))

Notice that the cabin cross-section at seat location is closer to rectangular than circular.

[image: Cessna 210 dimensional drawing 2]
([Source](https://www.wilderness-air.com/our-aircraft/cessna-210-n/))

So the interior cabin width is 105 cm, 42" at seat location. That is 3' 6". I guess the seat squabs are around 18" wide.

According to Wikipedia concerning commercial airline seats:

> Since the beginning of the 21st Century until 2018 average seat width decreased from 18.5 to 17 inches,

So it's similar to economy class on an airliner.

Answer (score 4):

The Cessna 210 Centurion has a maximum cabin width of 3’8” or 44” or 112cm. It is actually one of the larger single engine Cessna piston powered aircraft. The very popular Cessna 172 only has a 3’4” or 40” or 102cm cabin width.

Yes, the seats are very narrow but I can’t find any exact measurements.

Comment: Can you also tell me where the cabin width is usually measured ? At the widest point, or on the floor ? This can make quite a difference when the fuselage is about cylinder formed !

Comment: @Programmer Widest point.